# gulp, command not found - Worked fine before, then suddenly stopped

Tags: node.js, bash, npm, gulp

A couple of months ago I was creating web apps with the MEAN stack on windows 10. Then I had a break and now I am trying to get back into it.

Back then I was using gulp, browsersync, webpack and nodemon to automate my server restarting-process and I remember everything working fine. But. when I tried this a week ago it just replied **"bash: gulp: command not found"

I uninstalled and reinstalled both gulp the other packages globally and locally, but no difference. I decided to try making an entirely new app and installing everything from scratch, but I got the same results. I have spent hours on this issue, but none of the solutions I can find online is working.

**When I try to install gulp globally I get some warnings:** *(don't know if they have anything to do with it)*

> npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>
> npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.

**Gulp is installed to this location:**

```
C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\gulp -> C:\Users\<my username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js
```

Do anyone know how what might be my issue?

**If there is any other information you need, please let me know.** **Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to uninstall all global packages before installing the gulp globally. If you need remote packages in the future, remember them to install after.

Perhaps it also will help: https://demisx.github.io/gulp4/2015/01/15/install-gulp4.html

It shows how to completely uninstall the gulp and install it again.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!